# Nuxt 3 multiple domains/projects

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am building a Nuxt 3 SSR application, which I'm getting rather familiar with. What I can't wrap my head around, if it's even possible, is to have a single Nuxt project for multiple domains. For example, I have a few websites such as websitea.com, websiteb.com, websitec.com, and want to keep pages separate, while sharing components, compostables, etc. I'm not sure if this is possible, but it would be greatly appreciated if anyone has any advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this requirement too and came up with this solution:

Everything is shared as one Nuxt 3 app with a single `nuxt.config.ts`. The only difference is that each app has it's own sub-directory within `/pages`.

Here's how I set it up:

- Create a pages structure like this:

```
/pages
--/website1
--/website2
--/website3
```

- Define an env variable like `WEBSITE_ID` (e.g. within your project's `.env`)

```ini
WEBSITE_ID="website1"
```

- Inside of `nuxt.config.ts` add this configuration:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  //...
  dir: {
    pages: `pages/${process.env.WEBSITE_ID}`
  },
  //...
})
```

- When it's time to deploy your apps, inject the corresponding `WEBSITE_ID` env variable for each at build time.
- While in development, simply edit the `WEBSITE_ID` within the `.env` to switch which website you're working on.

This setup makes it so that for example, when `website1` is active, `pages/website1` is treated as the `/pages` directory... so `pages/website1/index.vue` would be resolved when requesting `/`.

Comment: Wow, that's so simple! Thank you so much; you took such a weight off my shoulders. It works like a charm!

Comment: I just thought of something: wouldn't this solution require multiple build instances?

Comment: @KeithPetrillo Yes, you'd have to build for each site. If you wanted only a single build / nuxt instance that serves all sites, you could probably remove the "dir" config from defineNuxtConfig and instead run a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx) in front of the nuxt instance with logic that proxies requests to 'website1.com/x' to 'localhost:port/website1/x'. You might also be able to mimic this behavior somehow with Cloudflare's page rules. I've never set this up though, so can't suggest specifics.

Comment: @KeithPetrillo You can also check out the "extends" feature of nuxt - I experimented with it but it was buggy / had some major performance issues. I'm sure it will improve over time though. This is a great video explaining it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvTui3P0w-o

Comment: Oh yea that makes a ton of sense. Thank you for sharing that!

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Nuxt 3, you're probably after Layers here: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/layers

A base app can be extended, thus sharing components etc with other apps.

Comment: Layers are more like a monorepo structure for Nuxt. You won´t be able to separate your project into multiple apps as layers extend from each other instead of being their own app.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be to create a library using [Nuxt Kit](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/kit). This library will contain all of your components, composables and everything you need to share between your projects. You will need to add your library as a dependency of your different websites.

If you don't want to deal with multiple git repositories you can create a monorepo. (For example using pnpm: https://pnpm.io/fr/workspaces)